# "Chemical work" term in Joule-Thomson Effect

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-potential

I am deriving the isenthalpic property of the Joule-Thomson effect, but always get a wrong result due to (probably) my naive understanding of thermodynamics.

Here, I will call the left section "section 1" and the right section "section 2", which are separated by a tiny hole in between them. I assume that the pressure is higher in 1 than 2, and it is kept constant by pistons on both ends of sections. Also, the system is thermally shielded from the environment.

$$\Delta E=-\frac{\Delta N}{N_1}E_1+\frac{\Delta N}{N_2}E_2$$
$$\Delta W =-\frac{\Delta N}{N_1}P_1V_1+\frac{\Delta N}{N_2}P_2V_2+\mu_1\Delta N-\mu_2\Delta N$$
By the adiabatic condition, $\Delta E+\Delta W=0$, leading to the isenthalpic condition **without chemical work terms**.

I included the chemical work terms because from the viewpoint of sections 1 and 2, they are losing particles / gaining particles, leading to the chemical work terms. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there something about the derivation of the open-system (control volume) version of the 1st law of thermodynamics that you are unhappy with?

Comment: @ChetMiller The thing is that I should get rid of chemical work terms in order to get correct result (conservation of specific enthalpy). Any idea?

Comment: Aren't the chemical potential terms supposed to represent the changes in internal energy at constant volume and entropy?  Certainly entropy changes in this irreversible situation.  I recommend working the the open system version of the first law once you understand its derivation.

Comment: I knew the definition of chemical potential but thought of it as a definition that can be used in cases where volume and entropy change by applying Maxwell relations to the definition. Maybe I should take a closer look at the derivation. Thank you for your kind explanation.